# Regular Expression to parse category steps

Tags: java, regex

I have this String

English>Arts>Photography

Want regular expression to delete all after last (>) ,Want output to be like this

English>Arts>

Many Thanks,

Comment: have U tried anything??

Comment: I tried substring(0, str.indexOf(">")) but it delete all after first(>) but i want to delete after the last not the first.

Comment: split based on ">" add arr[0] + ">" + arr[1]..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `String.lastIndexOf()` instead of `String.indexOf()`. no need to go to regexps for this

Answer (score 0):

Use **LastIndexOf** as mentioned below :

```
Substring(0, [YourString].LastIndexOf('>'));
```

Comment: don't forget to upvote and mark it as an answer if it is helpful. so that other users can use the same solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) and [lastIndexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) as shown below:

```
String s = "English>Arts>Photography";
System.out.println( s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf('>') ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really didn't want to use .lastIndexOf() (i don't know why you wouldn't). The regex would have been:

```
String input = "English>Arts>Photography";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*>)[A-Za-z]+");
Matcher m = p.mathcer(input);
if (m.matches()) {
 String output = m.group(1);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for you, but there is a simple edit in the regex you have to add(+) at the end of regex to match more than one character it must be like     .compile("(.*>)[A-Za-z]+");  again very thanks for your help.

Comment: gah, good spot. Didn't bother to test it locally as the problem was already solved!